# Measurements in pst-3dplot versus pst-solides3d

Tags: pstricks, 3d, pst-solides3d, pst-3dplot

My aim is to draw a circumscribed circle on the polygon
constructed as "cone base" using `pst-solides3d`.
By circumscription, I mean that the corners of the polygon
touch the circle from within.

I try to coerce a radius measure on the cone, with `r=2` option, but this does not align with the two half-axis vectors `(0,1,0)(1,0,0)` in the specification of `\pstThreeDCircle`.

[image: Vertical cone with circle surrounding base]

How do I specify measurements in `\pstThreeDCircle` and \psSolid[object=cone]` using aligning measurements of the two packages?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{frame}{Keglens overflade}
    % Voss: "PSTricks  - Grafik mit PostScript für Tex und LaTeX", p. 421
    \psset{lightsrc=10 5 20,viewpoint=50 20 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=20}
    \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,3)
        \pstThreeDCircle[linecolor=red](0,0,0)(0,1,0)(1,0,0)
        \psSolid[object=cone,h=5,r=2](0,0,0)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note: I added `,h=5,r=2` to cone options for height and radius of the cone, in accordance with the [pst-solides3d doc](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/43856019/pst-solides3d-the-documentation).

I tried to swap the loading sequence of PSTrick packages as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197846/36128) with no effect.

I tried to substitute `viewpoint` with `Aplha`and `Beta` as suggested
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384883/36128)
only to get the cone blown up covering the (tilted) circle.

Comment: it makes no sense to mix macros from `pst-solides3d` (central projection) and `pst-3dplot` (parallel view).

Comment: I ask because I take it my students need to focus on the circumference of the cone's circular base, when having to calculate the lateral area of the cone. I have no preferences t combine these packages, Alternative suggestions, @user187802 ?

Comment: @user187802: As to parallel view in `pst-3dplot`, isn't it the viewpoint you adjust with `Alpha` and `Beta`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2)(3,7.5)
    \psset{viewpoint=50 20 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=50, lightsrc=viewpoint} 
    \psSolid[object=cone,
    ngrid=20 24,
    r=2, h=6,
    fillcolor=yellow!25,
    intersectiontype=0,
    intersectionplan={
        [0 0 1 0]
        [0 0 1 -1]
        [0 0 1 -2]
        [0 0 1 -3]},
    intersectioncolor=(bleu) (rouge) (vert) (rose),
    intersectionlinewidth=2 2.5 2.8 3.2,
    linewidth=0.1pt,
    linecolor=black!20,
    action=draw**]
    \axesIIID(2,2,6)(3,3,7)
\end{pspicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can get around the inconsequence pointed out in comment by drawing a cylinder with `h=0` to impost a 3d circle:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Keglens overflade}
  \begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(2,3)
    \psSolid[object=cone,h=5,r=2](0,0,0)
    \psSolid[object=cylindre,linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,mode=5,h=0,r=2](0,0,-0.5)
  \end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Cone with circle of base drawn as cylinder]